# How to include font awesome icons in object by using Ngstyle or ngclass

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Can we include font awesome icons in an object by using ngstyle and how do we bind them in HTML?

I  tried the below code, but it is not working for me:

```
$scope.Items = [
 obj: {data:65476756,right:12344,title:"Income"},object:{ "font-size" : "20px", "text-align":"center" ,"icon":"fa fa-level-up"}]
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<div my-widget data="item.obj" ng-style="item.object"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is that an extra `}` at the end of `$scope.Items` ?

Comment: yaa  its actually with double objects in it i had removed it

Comment: any answers please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-style` expects the object keys are CSS style names and values are corresponding values for those CSS keys. As there is no CSS style named `icon` it is getting ignored.
`fa fa-level-up` are the CSS classes and they should be used like classes only.

So you need to change your JS code like:

```
$scope.Items = [{
 obj: {data:65476756,right:12344,title:"Income"},
 object:{ "font-size" : "20px", "text-align":"center"},
 classes:"fa fa-level-up"
}]
```

And then use it in HTML like:

```
<div my-widget data="item.obj" ng-style="item.object" ng-class="item.classes"> 
</div>
```

Note: `item.classes` is string.
Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

**Edit**

To answer your question about size, color, position: you can use standard CSS styles for this. For more info check this link: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/

> If you change the font-size of the icon's container, the icon gets
>   bigger. Same things goes for color, drop shadow, and anything else
>   that gets inherited using CSS.

Alternatively you can also use classes like `fa-2x`...`fa-5x`.

Comment: but how can increase size of an icon

Comment: and i want to change color and position  is that possible @Vivek Athalye

Comment: if i include two font icons the 1st one disppears and all the css styles applying to second how to include to fa fa icons @ Vivek Athalye

Comment: @pradeep search for `Stacked Icons` on the FA examples link I've given above.